# How to optimize tile rendering in pygame?

Tags: python, optimization, pygame, tiles-game

I am making a tile based game, and the map needs to be rendered every frame. Right now, each tile is 32X32, and the visible map is 28X28 tiles. The performance is dreadful. I recently made it only render the visible tiles, but this still did not improve the FPS much. Right now I'm looking for a way to speed up the rendering. I attribute the slowness to the way I am rendering ; every tile is individually blitted to the screen. What would be a more effective was of doing this?

Comment: Have you profiled and determined that rendering is the bottleneck?

Comment: Right now the program is only doing rendering and movement of one sprite, and the FPS is greatly increased when only the sprite is rendered.

Comment: The speed of the program might have noting to do with the rendering.  Try having the program not render and instead just print out the frames per second.  If it is still slow, post the code so we can see exactly how you did it and if it can be done in a faster way.

Comment: Could you show the code?  Do you keep the tile types in memory?  You should keep them in memory and perform convert() just after loading them.

Answer (score 2):

In pygame (afaik), updating the screen is always one hell of a bottle neck. Since I could not see your code, I don't know, how you are updating the screen. Only blitting the the sprites that changed is a start, but you need to only update those parts that changed, on the screen.
Basically it is the difference between using `display.flip()` or using `update_rects()` with only the changed rects. I know, that does not help at all, when you are scrolling the map. 
 Take a look at this question: [Why is this small (155 lines-long) Pacman game on Python running so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379102/why-is-this-small-155-lines-long-pacman-game-on-python-running-so-slow), it has a similiar topic.

One thing I tried when I had a map compiled of tiles and some sprites on it, I tried always having a precompiled image of the map for an area containing the currently displayed part and some 200 or so pixels around that, so that I could blit the prepared "ground" (still only in updated parts) without the need of blitting all those tiles contained in it. That, of course, is quite some thinking you have to put into that, espacially if you have multiple layers and parts of the map that can be above your active sprites. It is interesting to think and work that through, but I cannot tell you, how much you will gain by that.

One totally different possible solution: I began with pygame once (since I did SDL in C++ prior to that). Recently I was directed to another python gaming library: [pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/). This does not suffer from the problems of updating the whole screen as much as pygame (I think it's because of usage of OpenGL acceleration; it still works on my not at all accelerated eee-Netbook). If you are not bound to pygame in any way, it might be interesting to take a look at pyglet.